# Как сделать активным элемент по клику в списке?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

У меня есть конструктор класса **device**. И мне нужно отрендерить его **types** в отдельном компоненте.

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx'

export default class DeviceStorage {
    constructor() {
        this.types = [
            {id: 1, name: 'Laptops'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Smartphones'}
        ]
        this.brands = []
        this.devices = []
        this.selectedType = {}
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }

    setTypes(types) {
        this.types = types
    }

    setBrands(brands) {
        this.brands = brands
    }

    setDevices(devices) {
        this.devices = devices
    }

    setSelectedType(type) {
        this.selectedType = type
    }

    get Types() {
        return this.types
    }

    get Brands() {
        return this.brands
    }

    get Devices() {
        return this.devices
    }

    get SelectedType() {
        return this.selectedType
    }
}
```

Вот это я сделал с помощью **функции map**:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import {Context} from '../index'
import styles from '../styles/TypeBar.module.css'

import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'


const TypeBar = observer(() => {
    const {device} = useContext(Context)
    return (
        <ul className={styles.ListGroup}>
            {device.types.map(type => {
                return <li
                    key={type.id}
                    onClick={() => {device.setSelectedType(type)}}>
                    {type.name}
                </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    )
})

export default TypeBar
```

Тут все отлично отрисовывается, я также добавил новый setSelectedType и геттер для него также в самом конце. Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на один из отрисованных элементов **li** он становился активным. Есть идея добавить в его свойства следующее: `active={type.id === device.SelectedType.id}`. Но я не знаю, сработает ли подход, и как это в css отобразить?

```
.ListGroup li[active] {
    background: #20bdff;
}
```

В **index.js** , само собой, вызываю контекст для **device**.

```
<Context.Provider value={{
  device: new DeviceStorage()
}}/>
```

Я надеюсь, я нормально объяснил, в чем проблема, вот еще скрин:
[image: Список types]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите выделять `li` при клике.

Если это так, то решение ниже. Использовать атрибут active не рекомендую, т.к. по [спецификации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) у `li` нет данного атрибута. Используйте class или если хотите работать с атрибутом, то используйте data-* атрибут(например data-active)

```
export default function App() {
  const {device} = useContext(Context)
  const [select, setSelect] = useState(-1); // Создаем стейт для компонента
  // Он нужен, что бы заставлять компонент ререндерится при клике

  return (
    <ul className={"styles.ListGroup"}>
      {device.types.map((type) => {
        return (
          <li
            key={type.id}
            className={(select === type.id) ? "selectLi" : "sel"}
            onClick={() => {
              // Если надо передать выбранный компонент в ваш контекст
              device.setSelectedType(type); 
              // Пишем в стейт id(если одинаковые отключаем выделение)
              type.id === select ? setSelect(-1) : setSelect(type.id);                 
             }}
          >
            {type.name}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Тестировал решение здесь -> [https://codesandbox.io/s/async-sun-v7mwwm](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-sun-v7mwwm)

Comment: Спасибо что подсказали как это сделать, а то я долго мучался не получалось.