# Как реализовать метод добавление в избранное?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нужно сделать так, чтобы данные отображались поверх других данных. При этом изменять данные в фейк эйпиай не надо.

У меня есть метод, который находится в файле App.js:

```
const handleToggleBookMark = (id) => {
    setUsers(
      users.filter((user) => {
        if (user._id === id) {
          user.bookmark = !user.bookmark
          return user
        } 
        return user
      })
    )
  }

return (
    <div>
      <Users
        onToggleBookMark={handleToggleBookMark}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

А так же добавление в саму таблицу? в jsx файле:

```
<td>
    <BookMark status={bookmark} onClick={() => onToggleBookMark(_id)} />
</td>
```

И уже в другом компоненте мне нужна сама реализация.

```
const BookMark = ({ status, ...rest }) => {
  

}

export default BookMark
```

Кто подскажет как сделать?
Иконки я взял с буцтрапа в html файл уже подключил.

Comment: Залейте код в песочницу

Comment: Можете детализировать, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать? Что значит, данные должны отображаться поверх других? Пока, примерно, если я правильно понял, прочитав многократно, вы хотите сделать возможность отмечать некоторые записи как "Избранное" и что бы эти записи в списке всегда был в самом начале, а ниже шли остальные... Верно?

Comment: На данный момент мне нужно чтобы я их просто мог отметить. Так сказать поставить галочку, убрать галлочку и все

Comment: Посмотрите [вариант пример с галочками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1459137/1459174#1459174) и [про выделение элементов в списке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457778/1457911#1457911)? а так же [про создание динамических списков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478184/1478652#1478652). Вам надо создать переменную состояния, в которой вы будете хранить выбранные значения. Либо компонент высшего порядка, либо каждый компонент BookMark может обладать собственным состоянием.

Comment: @SwaD

(https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-liskov-22ii6s?file=/components/bookmark.jsx) _ссылка на песочницу_

Я залил основные моменты в коде. Хранить избранные нигде на данный момент не нужно. Необходимо просто иметь возможность менять условно изображение.

Comment: Зашел в вашу песочницу... Там ничего не работает и то что указано в вопросе не соответствует коду. + то что вы там указали работать будет.

Answer (score -1):

Решение нашел с помощью знакомого.
Реализация в файле bookmark.jsx

```
const BookMark = ({ status, onToggleBookMark, _id }) => {
  return (
    <i
      onClick={() => onToggleBookMark(_id)}
      class={status ? 'bi bi-star-fill' : 'bi bi-star'}
    ></i>
  )
}
```

А в файле user.jsx

```
<td>
    <BookMark
     status={bookmark}
     onToggleBookMark={onToggleBookMark}
     _id={_id}
    />
</td>
```

Было сложно описать проблему. Может кому пригодится.